# assign data to variable PHP

Tags: php, laravel, variables, crud, assign

I wan to get data for two variables in same method but its not happening

```
function display(){
    $datas=Req::all();
    $products = Product::all();
    return view ('products.dispaly')->with('products', $products,'datas',$datas);
}
```

here i want to get data from table and assign them to two separate variables $datas, and $ products? what is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `view` this way:

```php
return view(
    'products.dispaly',
    [
        'products' => $products,
        'datas' => $datas,
    ]
);
```

Another way that is exactly the same, just less verbose, is to use [`compact`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php):

```php
return view('products.dispaly', compact('products', 'datas'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have view name "dispaly"... I guess it should be: "display".

Try this:

```
    return view('products.display', ['products' => $products, 'datas' => $datas]);
```

or

```
    return view ('products.display')
                ->with('products', $products)
                ->with('datas',$datas);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have data in variables and want that data on the next page with the same name as the variables I prefer to use "compact" it is a php function that creates an array from variables and their values.

```
    function display() {
        $datas=Req::all();
        $products = Product::all();
        return view ('products.display', compact('products', 'datas'));
    }
```

This is the same like:

```
    function display() {
        $datas=Req::all();
        $products = Product::all();
        return view ('products.display', [
            'products' => $products,
            'datas' => $datas
        ]);
    }
```

But compact do it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

To have an easy code to understand use compact is the best way

```
return view('products.dispaly',compact('products','datas'));
```